# AS 3.1.3 gradle-4.1-all.zip Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

the build.gradle file content:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26

    lib_appcompat_v7 = 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    lib_support_v4 = 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    lib_support_design = 'com.androdi.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

sync failed. error like this:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1. 
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :thirdLibrary:WordPressEditor

Comment: help please, thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue today. Last week everything worked fine, but today gradle can't find com.android.support in jcenter nor in maven central.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Place google() upon jcenter(). Then Sync project again.

(2) Check if you have **offline mode disabled** in `File> Setting > Build, Execution... > Gradle > Offline work`. (**Uncheck this box**)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26

    lib_appcompat_v7 = 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    lib_support_v4 = 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    lib_support_design = 'com.androdi.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: It's can't Sync too. output is the same thing.
If I uncomment "//jcenter()",only use "google()",the output is:
>Could not find com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.1.
>Searched in the following locations:
>    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.8.1/bintray-release-0.8.1.pom
>    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.8.1/bintray-release-0.8.1.jar

It looks like that google() and jcenter() are conflict, any other solutions? thank you!

Comment: Don't comment jcenter(), use the build.gradle which i posted above.

Comment: Also check if you have added `apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'` after `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in your app level build.gradle. That is important too.

Comment: Make a new sample project and add your required dependency, check if this error come there also?